# Externalize Tikz picture result in error 'pdflatex -holt-on-error but shell escape is used

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, tikz-external, shell-escape

I am trying to externalize `tikz-picture` by using the externalize library. I am using Miktex 2.9. I activate the external feature by using

```
\tikzexternalize
```

and also tried

```
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]
```

I just use the command mentioned in the manual:

```
pdflatex -shell-escape main
```

and start this in the commandfunction of windwos inside the directory with the main.tex I even tried choosing the pdflatex.exe directly. At the beginning it seems fine, he creates `main-figure0` files but then suddenly stopped with an error:

> ! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -halt-on-error - 
>   interaction=batchmode -jobname "main-figure0" \def\tikzexternalrealjob{main}\input{main}"
>   ' did NOT result in a usable output file 'main-figure0' (expected one of
>   .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please verify that you have enabled system calls. For pdflatex, 
>   this is 'pdflatex -shell-escape'.

The tikz-picture itseld seems to right as without externalize it is drawn since it just contains a

```
\draw (1,0) to (2,4);
```

Without externalize this compiles fine.

**Added MWE:**

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize

\begin{document}
hello
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (1,0) to (2,4);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I used:

> pdflatex -shell-escape external_test

figure0.log says at the end:

```
[1]
! Missing } inserted.
<inserted text> 
            }
l.12 \end{document}
```

**Real structure of the project:**

```
Main.tex
    -> \documentclass{scrbook}
        [...] usepackages
        \externalize

         \begin{document}
         \input{standalone_file.tex}
         \end{document}

standalone_file.tex
        -> \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
        [...] usepackages

         \begin{document}
         [tikzpicure_environment]
         \end{document}
```

Anyone an idea?

Comment: To me, this setup looks strange. Do you really externalize from a standalone document? When using article with the respective usepackage it should work as intended.

Comment: I don't quite get this: You are externalizing pictures that are in separate standalone files? Why not using one or the other version? This way seems very tricky for no additional benefit.

Comment: I use the standalone_file just for creation of the picture to check if it looks right. At the end i have to compile the tikzpicture using the main_file to make sure all references and all fonts are the same. But i see you are right, i can just use the .pdf by using \includepicture

Comment: Use `\usepackage{tikz}` instead of [tikz] and compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape %`. Then it should work.  If you like to save your tikz figures in an extra folder you could use `\tikzexternalize%[prefix=TikzPDFs/]` with `\tikzsetnextfilename{YourFileNameOfOutputA}`before every `tikzpicture`.

Comment: @SRel have you to tried it? Does it work for you too?